# Two operations in a single redirect

Tags: asp.net

I am doing a redirect in my asp.net page using C#. I have to give a redirect from tis page to a new one and preserve the old one too.  Some web sites have this feature , while clicking the play button is some players, the movie is start playing and it also opens a new webpage. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Opening a new window is easily done, simply use Javascript. Use `window.open()` in the onClick method of the button and use your normal method to deal with the original page.

Comment: I am looking for the code, exactly like done in some video sites. Open an AD parallely while giving the current action a switch on. I dont want to use js for this.